# How do you allow users to upload 2 excel files in a Python script via terminal, than download a new file file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, terminal

I have built a data processing tool using pandas. My script takes 2 very large excel files (Over 17000 rows) converts into dfs and summarises and merges the 2 dataframes. This leaves me with one final df. My problem is I want this script to be used by people other than me. I am able to obtain values for certain variables by using the input function (Using Python 3)

For example:

```
WinRate = input("Enter the Win Rate Percentage:")
```

But I'm struggling to find a way to allow the users to upload 2 files to actually run the script on. I'd than want them to be able to download the subsequent output file. Any help you can give me would be most appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: maybe you can let the people upload 2 files by `FTP` with fix name and path. then handle the files with your script. People can also download the output file from FTP.

Comment: You can create a simple gui with Tkinter. Tkinter has a function to show a filedialog. You can then ask your users for the 2 input files (one after the other) and a filename for the output. You can then use those filenames in your script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a simple gui with Tkinter. Tkinter has a function to show a filedialog. You can then ask your users for the 2 input files (one after the other) and a filename for the output. You can then use those filenames in your script

```
import tkinter
import tkinter.filedialog

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.withdraw() # Remove background screen

# Ask for name of inputfiles
excelfile1 = tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilename(parent=root, title="Select first Excel file", defaultextension = ".xlsx")
excelfile2 = tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilename(parent=root, title="Select second Excel file", defaultextension = ".xlsx")

# Ask for name of outputfile
output_excel = tkinter.filedialog.asksaveasfilename(parent=root, title="Give name of outputfile", defaultextension=".xlsx")
# ... Use excel files in the rest of your script
```

Comment: Excellent. Thanks for this Niels. Once I create a new df based on the data processed in the 2 excel files, how would I than allow the user to download the new file I make?

Comment: You could for example add a filedialog and ask them where they want to save the output file and then save (or copy) the file you make to that location. Is that an option?

Comment: That is certainly an option! So would I save it the same way as your solution i.e.

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.withdraw() # Remove background screen

outputfile = tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilename(parent=root, title="Choose where to save the file", defaultextension = ".xlsx")

Comment: See my edit above. The function for entering a non-existing filename (for the outputfile) is slightly different (`tkinter.filedialog.asksaveasfilename(...)`)

Comment: Excellent. Thank you :)